# What do you need to define a map of monads?

Tags: category-theory, monads

Suppose I have a monad $M_S = \langle S , \eta_S, \mu_S \rangle$ and a monad map given by a natural transformation $\phi: T \rightarrow S$.  What are the natural transformations of the resulting monad?

$$\langle S , \eta_S, \mu_S \rangle \rightarrow \langle T , ?, ? \rangle  $$

I am looking at [Street 72](https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=the+theory+of+monads&btnG=#d=gs_qabs&t=1672331794323&u=%23p%3DlElF9Ic5_U0J) and in it he defines a monad functor.  I am using this paper to get my definition of a monad map by saying that the functor $U$ is identity.

[image]

Edit: someone is now stating that I have to fill in the natural transformations of the image monad, like this

$$\langle S , \eta_S, \mu_S \rangle \rightarrow \langle T , 
\eta_T, \mu_T \rangle  $$

So, where do we start when defining a monad map?  Do we say that we have two monads and IF you have a natural transformation $\phi$ as above, you have a monad map?

Comment: What do you mean by "change the natural transformations"?

Comment: @KevinArlin hi can you help now after my edits?

Comment: A monad map/morphism is defined with respect to two monads. In your notation, you must require there to be a monad $M_T$. You seem to have gotten mixed up, and are trying to define a monad from a natural transformation, which isn't something you can generally do.

Comment: @varkor hi would you consider writing down how to define a monad map and how it relates to Street's monad functor definition?

Comment: Monad maps/morphisms between monads on the same category are defined, for instance, just after (2.4) in [this paper](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/18/14/18-14.pdf). Street's definition is a generalisation to monads on different categories: the simpler definition is recovered by taking $U$ to be the identity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following definition appears in [*Toposes, Triples and Theories* by Barr and Wells](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/reprints/articles/12/tr12abs.html), Section 3.6 (page 110), as well as in [*Dense morphisms of monads* by Karazeris and Velebil](http://www.tac.mta.ca/tac/volumes/18/14/18-14abs.html), Section 2.1 (page 4).

> **Definition 1.**
> Let $(T, μ_T, η_T)$ and $(S, μ_S, η_S)$ be two monads on a category $\mathcal{C}$.
> A morphism of monads from $(T, μ_T, η_T)$ to $(S, μ_S, η_S)$ is a natural transformation $α$ from $T$ to $S$ such that the following two diagrams commute:
> $$
>  \require{AMScd}
>  \begin{CD}
>   T           @>{α}>> S            \\
>   @A{η_T}AA           @AA{η_S}A    \\
>   \mathrm{Id} @=      \mathrm{Id}
>  \end{CD}
>  \qquad\qquad
>  \begin{CD}
>   T^2        @>{αα}>>  S^2        \\
>   @V{μ_T}VV            @VV{μ_S}V  \\
>   T          @>>{α}>   S
>  \end{CD}
> $$

Here the natural transformation $α α$ is given by $α S ∘ T α$, or equivalently by $S α ∘ α T$.

This definition only deals with monads on the same category.
For monads on two different categories, the following can be used:

> **Definition 2.**
> Let $(T, μ_T, η_T)$ be a monad on a category $\mathcal{C}$ and let $(s, μ_S, η_S)$ be a monad on a category $\mathcal{D}$.
> A morphism of monads from $(T, μ_T, η_T)$ to $(s, μ_S, η_S)$ consists of a functor $F \colon \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ and a natural transformation $α \colon SF \Rightarrow FT$ such that the following two diagrams commute:
> $$
>  \begin{CD}
>   SF           @>{α}>>  FT          \\
>   @A{η_S F}AA           @AA{F η_T}A \\
>   F            @=       F
>  \end{CD}
>  \qquad\qquad
>  \begin{CD}
>   S^2 F        @>{Sα}>>  S F T  @>{αT}>>  F T^2      \\
>   @V{μ_S F}VV            @.               @VV{F μ_T}V  \\
>   S F          @>{α}>>   T F    @=        F T
>  \end{CD}
> $$

The first definition is a special case of the second definition, by considering for $F$ the identity functor.

The above definitions apply to monads on categories.
However, the notion of a monad can be generalized to objects in $2$-categories by replacing categories with objects, functors with morphisms, and natural transformations with $2$-morphisms.
(Instead of “objects”, “morphisms” and “$2$-morphisms” one can also use the terms “$0$-cells”, “$1$-cells” and “$2$-cells”.)
The previous notion of a monad on a category is then the same as a monad in the $2$-category $\mathsf{Cat}$.

Definitions 1 and 2 can then also be applied to monads in $2$-categories.
The resulting definitions of morphisms between monads in $2$-categories can be found [in the nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad#the_bicategory_of_monads), as well as in [*The formal theory of monads* by Ross Street](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404902001378), which was already mentioned in the question.